# How to get name/confidence individually from classify_text?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-nl

Most of the other methods in the language api, such as analyze_syntax, analyze_sentiment etc, have the ability to return the constituent elements like

```
sentiment.score
sentiment.magnitude
token.part_of_speech.tag
etc etc etc....
```

but I have not found a way to return name and confidence in isolation from classify_text. It doesn't look like it's possible but that seems weird. Am missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [language.documents.classifyText](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1/documents/classifyText) method returns a [ClassificationCategory](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/reference/rest/v1/ClassificationCategory) object which contains `name` and `confidence`. If you only want one of the fields you can filter by `categories/name` or `categories/confidence`. As an example I executed:

```
POST https://language.googleapis.com/v1/documents:classifyText?fields=categories%2Fname&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "document": {
  "content": "this is a test for a StackOverflow question. I get an error because I need more words in the document and I don't know what else to say",
  "type": "PLAIN_TEXT"
 }
}
```

Which returns:

```
{
 "categories": [
  {
   "name": "/Science/Computer Science"
  },
  {
   "name": "/Computers & Electronics/Programming"
  },
  {
   "name": "/Jobs & Education"
  }
 ]
}
```

[Direct link](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/documents/m/language/v1/language.documents.classifyText?fields=categories%252Fname&_h=5&resource=%257B%250A%20%20%2522document%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%2522content%2522%253A%20%2522this%20is%20a%20test%20for%20a%20StackOverflow%20question.%20I%20get%20an%20error%20because%20I%20need%20more%20words%20in%20the%20document%20and%20I%20don't%20know%20what%20else%20to%20say%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%2522type%2522%253A%20%2522PLAIN_TEXT%2522%250A%20%20%257D%250A%257D&) to API explorer for interactive testing of my example (change content, filters, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. I seem to have forgotten to be more specific. Do you know what the syntax is in python? --edit oh my gosh never mind i found it right in the documentation. https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/classify-text-tutorial idk why it took me so long